# Cloud Functions >Firebas Realtime database index.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase realtime database in Android app, and have data like this:
I want to delete the "point": tab of all users.

Realtime Database

[image]

I want to do that with Cloud Functions. I don't know what code to put into index.js

Cloud Functions IMG

[image]

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * @function HTTP trigger that, when triggered by a request, checks every message of the database to delete the expired ones.
 * @type {HttpsFunction}
 */
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const timeNow = Date.now();
    const messagesRef = admin.database().ref('/users');
    messagesRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            if ((Number(child.val()['point'])) <= timeNow) {
                child.ref.set(null);
            }
        });
    });
    return res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may study the Get Started documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and the documentation that explains how to handle Realtime Database triggers https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events. If you encounter any problem with your code, please share this code and we will be able to help you.

Comment: i wrote my code above. but it gives such error. "Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com"

Comment: When do you get this error? When deploying (as explained in the Get Started help) or when calling the HTTP Cloud Function?

Comment: yeah I'm getting it on error

Comment: But **when** are you getting this error? When doing which action? In which error log?

Comment: maybe there is an error in my code

Comment: Triggeri gives error when I run

Comment: So can you describe in your question how you run it. Which URL are you using to run the Cloud Function? You need to give as much context information as possible. For us to help you we need to understand what you see on your screen, how you did you get to this situation, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am not getting the error now but the code does not delete places I want

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Cloud console to write functions that make use of the `firebase-functions` module.  You need to deploy the code through the Firebase CLI.  The CLI will make sure the function environment is set up properly so that the Firebase Admin SDK can initialize with the correct values.  The Cloud console won't do this for you.

Comment: what code do I write to get the result I want? Can you help?